# Skipping version creation of paper_trail when creating child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I have a simple model with an after_create filter that creates association records.

```
class Subject
  after_create :create_topics!

  has_paper_trail :on => [:create, :update],
                  :ignore => [:topics]

  private

  def create_topics!
    self.account.default_topics_for_subject_type(self.subject_type).each do |topic|
      self.topics.create!({:name => topic.name})
    end
  end
end
```

However, creating a `Subject` now which e.g will create two topics results in two versions for the same subject, a `create` before and an `update` after the topics have changed.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**update**
The topic model is not a subclass from subject, but belongs to it. They also have a paper_trail and should be versioned right from the beginning of the creation process through subject.

```
class Topic
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

Comment: Is Topic a subclass of Subject?  If so Topic will inherit the callback,  and it will get triggered by self.topics.create

Comment: Topic is a separate model, not a subclass.

Comment: Updated question, feel like I didn't provided everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
private

def create_topics!
  account.default_topics_for_subject_type(subject_type).each_with_index do |topic, index|
    if index == 0
      create_topic!(topic)
    else
      without_versioning { create_topic!(topic) }
    end
  end
end

def create_topic!(topic)
  self.topics.create!({:name => topic.name})
end
```

Comment: Does this work when I want to have the topics itself versioned from the beginning (having the create event of them when creating the subject) ?

Comment: I don't think so. Otherwise, I read that if you create the topic and set it's foreign key on subject manually, it won't trigger papertrail for the subject. Clear?

Comment: Both won't work the way intended. Funny thing: when I declare the `create_topics!` public and call it on the subject, I don't get new versions (because of the `:skip` array). It's really just the create callback. I don't have any other after_save or after_create callbacks which could interfer this.